# VMWare Ubuntu 14.04 not reading ram

Tags: virtual-machines, lvm, vmware-vsphere, ubuntu-14.04

I have a vm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Everything was working fine. I allocated some more ram to it but VSphere is now saying it doesnt have any of that ram now. Vmware says the ram is unaccessed per second picture. How can I make sure that this cpu uses all of it memory allocated?

Picture-1

[image: 1]

---

Picture-2

[image: 2]

Here is what you get from `$free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         20080       5311      14768          1        188       3659
-/+ buffers/cache:       1463      18617
Swap:         8187          0       8187
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Let's see if I understand: you had a running VM and needed to add RAM to it. So you shut it down, added RAM, started it back up, and then what? You're surprised that it's not instantly consuming all of the RAM you gave it?

Comment: Yes....it decreased the ram to lower what it was before...now web server running slow...any way to get it to recognize ram faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is working as intended. You've allocated ~20G RAM to this VM, and your server OS reports its available RAM correctly. If your server is performing slow, it is likely just due to its disk cache needing to be warmed. After a reboot, no disk contents are cached in RAM. As processes read files off of disk, that data gets cached in RAM and future reads of that data are served directly out of RAM instead of disk.

Give your system some time, and its performance should meet or exceed past performance. If you really want to get into things, you can use [vmtouch](https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) to manually manipulate your OSes cache, but be careful, you should really only do this as a last resort, and only if you have a deep understanding of the kernel's virtual memory system.

Comment: I allocated the space yesterday. So how long do you think it would take? And is it normal for RAM to drop to lower than it originally was first?

Comment: It depends on how much usage your server is seeing. There are far too many variables to put a number on it. And as far as "is it normal", yes, it's completely normal for the kernel to be using less RAM for cache after a reboot than before a reboot.

Comment: So I really need to be able to use all of this ram how would I use this vmtouch to manipulate the cache

Comment: Read the documentation, but beware, you may actually *decrease* performance if you do it wrong. Your best bet is just to wait it out. If it's really that much of a problem, investigate getting faster disk on your server.